# Add a css class to tr fails

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, addclass, bootstrap-table

I am using [Bootstrap Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) where I load my data remotly with `data-url="data.json"`. So my table:

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-hover" data-url="data.json" data-toggle="table" id="table-pagination"  data-pagination="true">
    <thead>
         <tr>
              <th data-field="id" data-align="center">id</th>
              <th data-field="type" data-align="center">type</th>
              <th data-field="name" data-align="center">name</th>
              <th data-field="product" data-align="center">product</th>
              <th data-field="use" data-align="center">use</th>
              <th data-field="quantity" data-sortable="true">quantity</th> 
         </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

where tha last column has numbers only (without any other characters). The data.json is like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 120,
        "type": "type1",
        "name": "name 1",
        "product": "250304-01",
        "use": "use 1",
        "quantity": 10000
    },
    {
        "id": 121,
        "type": "type2",
        "description": "name 2",
        "product": "250124-01",
        "cutter": "use 1",
        "quantity": 80
    }
]
```

I want to check, when the value in the last column is smaller than 100 then a class to be added in that `tr`. I searched about it and I found that this can be done with `filter`. So, I code this:

```
 $('tbody tr').filter( function(){
                       return $('td:last', this).text() < 100;
                     }).addClass('warning');
```

I save the above as it is to a file `addWarning.js` and I put it at the bottom of my page in the end of all the other `scripts`.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-table-el-GR.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/addWarning.js"></script>
```

But it isn't working.. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this to see where you issue is occuring (i.e. is it the selector, or in the filter function)?

Comment: @PranavCBalan how I do the check after the adding?

Comment: `addWarning.js` or `addWarnings.js` ? Or is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada i editted , thx for noticing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the table row only after remote content is loaded, otherwise  `$('tbody tr')` will not select any element. So you can bind event handler for **[`load-success.bs.table`](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#events)** event , it fires when remote data is loaded successfully.

```
$('table').on('load-success.bs.table', function() {
  $('tbody tr').filter(function() {
    return $('td:last', this).text() < 100;
  }).addClass('warning');
});
```

Comment: Can I ask you sth else? In that table there is a function where I can sort the records by the quantity. See here http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/. When I sort the class warning is removed.. What I have to add to check continuously the value?

Comment: @yaylitzis : then use `reset-view.bs.table` event

Comment: Great, just great! Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

> I save the above as it is to a file addWarning.js and I put it at the
>   bottom of my page in the end of all the other scripts.

This means the script runs when it is hit - which is during the page loading process.  At this point the bootstrap table hasn't loaded the data, so the filter doesn't match.

According to the documentation page: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/ you'll need to listen for `load-success.bs.table`, you should be able to replace your existing code directly with something like:

```
$(function() {
    $(body).on("load-success.bs.table", function() {
        $('tbody tr').filter( function(){
                   return $('td:last', this).text() < 100;
                 }).addClass('warning');
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `rowStyle` option, `data-row-style="rowStyle"`, and then:

```
function rowStyle(row) {
    if (row.quantity < 100) {
        return {
            classes: 'warning'
        };
    }
    return {};
}
```

Docs: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#table-options

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/3270/

Answer (score 0):

```
var tr = $('#mytable tbody tr')

tr.each(function () {
    var td = $(this).find('td:last');
    alert(td.text());
    if (td.text() < 100) {
        td.addClass('warning')
    }


})
```

Try it this way

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e5d1no6x/)